# how to save an array as a grayscale image with matplotlib/numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to save a numpy array of dimensions 128x128 pixels into a grayscale image.
I simply thought that the pyplot.imsave function would do the job but it's not, it somehow converts my array into an RGB image.
I tried to force the colormap to Gray during conversion but eventhough the saved image appears in grayscale, it still has a 128x128x4 dimension.
Here is a code sample I wrote to show the behaviour :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mplimg
from matplotlib import cm

x_tot = 10e-3
nx = 128

x = np.arange(-x_tot/2, x_tot/2, x_tot/nx)

[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x,x)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

diam = 5e-3
I = np.exp(-2*(2*R/diam)**4)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(I, extent = [-x_tot/2, x_tot/2, -x_tot/2, x_tot/2])

print I.shape

plt.imsave('image.png', I)
I2 = plt.imread('image.png')
print I2.shape

mplimg.imsave('image2.png',np.uint8(I), cmap = cm.gray)
testImg = plt.imread('image2.png')
print testImg.shape
```

In both cases the results of the "print" function are (128,128,4).

Can anyone explain why the imsave function is creating those dimensions eventhough my input array is of a luminance type?
And of course, does anyone have a solution to save the array into a standard grayscale format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `PIL` it should work like this

```
from PIL import Image

I8 = (((I - I.min()) / (I.max() - I.min())) * 255.9).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(I8)
img.save("file.png")
```

Comment: The rescaling can evidently be done differently, but passing `uint8` values makes things unambiguous to PIL

Answer (score 3):

There is also an alternative of using [imageio](https://imageio.github.io/). It provides an easy and convenient API and it is bundled with Anaconda. It can save grayscale images as a single color channel file.

Quoting the documentation

```
>>> import imageio
>>> im = imageio.imread('imageio:astronaut.png')
>>> im.shape  # im is a numpy array
(512, 512, 3)
>>> imageio.imwrite('astronaut-gray.jpg', im[:, :, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a possibility to use [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/), then there is no need to convert numpy array into a PIL object.

```
from skimage import io
io.imsave('output.tiff', I.astype(np.uint16))
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to use PIL in my code and as noted in the question I ran into the same problem with pyplot, where even in grayscale, the file is saved in MxNx3 matrix.

Since the actual image on disk wasn't important to me, I ended up writing the matrix as is and reading it back "as-is" using numpy's save and load methods:

```
np.save("filename", image_matrix)
```

And:

```
np.load("filename.npy")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that you can use, as stated in the other answers.

Answering your question, for matplotlib, **my guess** is that for *.png* files, they are converting the 2D grayscale image for an RGBA (still in grayscale) 3D array. See [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.0rc1/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L1616C15-L1616C15) in matplotlib's GtiHub. That is why your read image is a 3D array instead of a 2D.

Check this minimal working example below that uses [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html), [Opencv](https://opencv.org/) and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Note, matplotlib also uses pillow as does recommend using it on [plt.imread](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) page.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image

im = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)

#### Using matplotlib ####
print("Using matplotlib ------")
print(im.shape)

plt.imsave('test.png', im, cmap='gray', pil_kwargs={'compress_level':0})

print(os.path.getsize('test.png'), 'bytes')

im_r_plt = plt.imread('test.png')

print(im_r_plt.shape)

#### Using PIL ####
print("Using PIL ------")
img = Image.fromarray(im)
img.save('test.png', compress_level=0)

print(os.path.getsize('test.png'), 'bytes')

im_r_pil = Image.open('test.png') 

print(im_r_pil.size)

#### Using opencv ####
print("Using opencv ------")
cv2.imwrite('test.png', im, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])

print(os.path.getsize('test.png'), 'bytes')

im_r_cv2 = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

print(im_r_cv2.shape)
```

The code outputs:

```bash
Using matplotlib ------
(100, 100)
40263 bytes
(100, 100, 4)
Using PIL ------
10168 bytes
(100, 100)
Using opencv ------
10180 bytes
(100, 100)
```