# python - matplotlib.pyplot saves binary mask with 4 channels(?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save binary masks, i.e. arrays with False and True values, as .png files.

However, when doing so with matplotlib.pyplot, it saves the image with 4 channels and I don't know why.

For example to save the image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

m = np.array([[False, True],
             [False, True]])

plt.imsave("mask.png", m, cmap=cm.gray)
```

Then reading it again and printing the shape:

```
plt.imread("mask.png").shape
```

Gives me:

(2, 2, 4)

Any reason for that and how to just save it as plain grayscale with 0/1 values so that the shape essentially will just be (2,2)?

Comment: Since all of the three RGB layers are the same, you can extract your original mask with `arr[:, :, 0]`, with `arr` being the mask loaded by `imread`. You can also convert it back to a Boolean array `a[:, :, 0].astype(bool)`

Comment: Okay, this workaround seem to work for me, thanks. But anyway I'm still curious why is it doing it in the first place?

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of imsave, but it is obvious that it has to create a file that adheres to the file structure defined by the extension, e.g., jpg, png, eps etc. There are other libraries like PIL that can deal with greyscale images directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929408/8881141 If you retrieve a Boolean array in the end, you don't even have to scale it `Image.fromarray(m.astype(np.uint8)).save("maskgrey.png")`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It is related to `matplotlib.pyplot`. Use library `PIL` and the png file has only 1 channel.

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(img).save('img.png')
```

If you're dealing with a float image, you also have to convert it before to uint8. For example like this:

```
img = 255 * img
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```